# Execute ffmpeg command without waiting for completion

Tags: php, ffmpeg, command, execute, procedural

I want to continuously run a ffmpeg command in php and when this process is running other php methods need to execute in their own process without waiting for the ffmpeg command to complete.  How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've tried?

Comment: cleaned up language in post and title

Answer (score 0):

Look into [CRON](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)
It lets you schedule tasks you want to run in the background at a specified pattern.